# How to calculate the transmission distance from satellite to earth (How to understand the formula)

Tags: math, transmission, space

I have this question in one of my tutorials and I cannot seem to find clarity in the question - I am trying to make an algorithm to do this all automatically but I need to understand the formula

I have one question

- where does the "10^-3" come from in the calculation?

[image: Question]

Comment: It comes from 5ms

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs an attempt at a solution and this is a math problem not a circuit problem

Comment: The formula is given \$d=v * t = c * t\$

Comment: Conversion of input data into proper SI units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10^-3 comes from the ***milli*** prefix in milliseconds, i.e. 5ms on the first question and 25ms on the second question.